# Javascript: Stop SetInterval

Tags: javascript, jquery, setinterval

I cannot figure out how to stop my setinterval code. I've seen the other posts on stackoverflow however nothing works.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var content =  tinyMCE.getContent('content').value;
});
var myinterval = setInterval(function() {
  $.get("status.php?id=<?php echo $id; ?>",function(data){     
    val = content.value;
    if (val != data) {
      $.pnotify({
        title: 'Regular Notice',
        text: 'Check me out! I\'m a notice.'
      });
      clear();
    }
  });
}, 1000 * 2 * 1); 

function clear(){
    clearInterval(myinterval);
}
```

Comment: `setInterval()` returns an ID, you should clear the interval using that ID.

Comment: In this instance, I wouldn't use a set interval anyway, I would use a setTimeout when the ajax call from $.get is complete, to make sure the previous call has complete before starting the next!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**setInterval()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/window.setInterval) return unique interval ID which you can pass to [**clearInterval()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.clearInterval) to cancels repeated action.

```
//Capture interval id in a variable
var myinterval = setInterval(function () {
    $.get("status.php?id=<?php echo $id; ?>", function (data) {
        val = content.value;
        if (val != data) {
            $.pnotify({
                title: 'Regular Notice',
                text: 'Check me out! I\'m a notice.'
            });

            //Call clear method
            clear();
        }
    });
}, 1000 * 2 * 1);

function clear() {
    //Call method with defined ID
    clearInterval(myinterval);
}
```

Comment: bit of explanation might be in order here

Comment: Games of spot-the-difference make for poor answers.

Comment: @Satpal, should this code work as is, or do I have to somehow run the variable myinterval? Because if I replace what I had before this does not work.

Comment: @Cody, What did you got? And you edited the question

Answer (score 1):

You have to capture the interval id and pass it to `clearInterval`.

```
var intervalId = setInterval(function() {
```

and

```
clearInterval(intervalId);
```